# AWS Athena SQL query question: how to merge two cell values into one cell with condition

Tags: sql, presto, trino, amazon-athena

I'm new to SQL and currently using AWS Athena for the first time, and wonder if this kind of manipulation is possible using SQL.

Current data is as below (contains a conversation between A and B):

`table name: conversation`

| sender | message |
| --- | --- |
| A | Hello |
| B | Hi |
| A | I have a question. |
| A | May I ask? |
| B | Sure! |
| B | What is it? |

And my goal is to create this table:

| sender | message |
| --- | --- |
| A | Hello |
| B | Hi |
| A | I have a question. May I ask? |
| B | Sure! What is it? |

I tried using `array_join` with `array_agg` like this:

```sql
SELECT sender, array_join(array_agg(message), ',') as new_message FROM conversation
GROUP BY sender
```

But it concatenates everything in the group regardless of the order of the conversation, so it's not ideal in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi - how do you/we know the order in which to process the records, given that the rows in a table have no intrinsic order?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some column which will define the order of messages - like unique incremental id of message in chat or timestamp, otherwise the order is not deterministic which can lead to incorrect results due to the distributed nature of the Presto. If you have one, then you can use gaps-and-islands approach based on [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) ('lag' in particular):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(msg_id, sender, message) AS (
 values (1, 'A', 'Hello'),
    (2, 'B', 'Hi'),
    (3, 'A', 'I have a question.'),
    (4, 'A', 'May I ask?'),
    (5, 'B', 'Sure!'),
    (6, 'B', 'What is it?')
),

-- query parts
with_lag_bit as(
    select *,
       if(lag(sender) over (order by msg_id) != sender, 1, 0) lag_bit
    from dataset
),
with_group as(
    select *,
       sum(lag_bit) over (order by msg_id) grp
    from with_lag_bit
)

select sender, array_join(array_agg(message), ' ')
from with_group
group by sender, grp
order by grp;
```

Output:

| sender | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Hello |
| B | Hi |
| A | I have a question. May I ask? |
| B | Sure! What is it? |

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Iceberg Table you can use also Merge Into.
Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/merge-into-statement.html